# Two key maps conflict in vim, need to know why

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

from cscope i got this nmap:

```
nmap <C-\>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```

and i had these maps originally:

```
nmap <tab> v>
nmap <s-tab> v<
vmap <tab> >gv
vmap <s-tab> <gv
```

Now if i type s, then it will jump to the definition with one side effect:
it will tab the target line or target function/class content.

I can't find out where is this conflict. It seems that these two maps have no relationship.

Comment: Do you have a trailing `<Tab>` in your mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried out your mappings w/o any issue, so I assume there might be some kind of trailing charter issue like @glts suggested in his comment. Use `:set list` to show invisible characters.

However there are somethings you may want to consider:

- Unless you are mapping to a plugin or a very special need you should almost always use `nnoremap` over `nmap` to prevent recursive mappings.
- The vim way to indent/unindent is to use `>>` / `<<` (or `>` / `<` in visual mode). If you want to repeat the command then use `.`. The dot command will redo the last change. You can use `u` to undo if you have gone to far. Although I understand the want for mappings such as these, learning and making a habit to use `.` will help you in your journey to vim nirvana.
- Example of nice usage of the `.` command by showing off quick and dirty substitution.

  - Search for a common pattern in you file `/pat`
  - Change text to something else via `c`. e.g. `cgnfoo<esc>`
  - The `gn` motion will select the current pattern
  - repeat with `.` command.

For more help see:

```
:h mapping
:h .
:h u
:h >>
```

Comment: Yes, there really is a traillig <tab> in the cscope.vim configuration.Thank you.